# Cannot Access Non-System Databases in SQL Server Express 2016

Tags: sql-server, restore

after I allowed someone access to my SQL Server Express 2016 through team viewer,
I suddenly cannot access non-system databases. No problem with system ones, but I cannot access my other databases. Any ideas?Please see below screenshot

[image]

@RDFozz: (Sorry, replies below are disabled) Yes, I knew the user and I am connected as the same user.

Comment: First: do you know what the other person did while connected to your system? Are you sure they were legitimate? If not, your system may be compromised in general. Assuming that's not the case, are you sure you're connected as the same user you normally would be? You can confirm this with `SELECT SUSER_NAME();`. If you're not connected as the user you are normally connected as, exit SSMS and get back in (or, if necessary, log out of your computer and back in).

Comment: FYI - based on what I assume was your attempted edit (I rejected it for now, just in case). If you've forgotten your password, or accidentally created another account, see the "My account" section on the [Help](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help) page (link at bottom of page).

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of your screenshot, it looks like your query is not connected to the `BERNARDO\SQLEXPRESS01` instance and is connected to the `BERNARDO\SQLEXPRESS` instance (as indicated at the bottom of the query tab).  Change the connection of that query pane to connect to `BERNARDO\SQLEXPRESS01` and I suspect your issue will be resolved.

[image]